# colors palette in wordpress e-commerce theme

Tags: html, wordpress, colors

I am not able to find the colors palette code in a word press theme, I asked the designer and he told me I need to add HTML color codes manually, but I don't know where. attached is the image, where the color patterns are missing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5HMX.png)

Comment: Please make your question with proper details like issue, theme name, coding issue, etc. Otherwise its difficult to help you.

Comment: I purchased a theme for my eCommerce website, but now the issue is whenever I import any product, it doesn't show the colors in some attributes when I contacted the developer they ask me to input the HTML color codes manually, but I am not able to understand that,  where to input those html codes in theme. I have already attached the screenshot of the issue I am facing.

Comment: Still you didn't shared the theme name. Please share the theme name so i will check its demo and update you.

Comment: The theme name is Shella, and the link for theme is https://themeforest.net/item/shella-fashion-store-woocommerce-theme/23661366

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

create variable product add attribute there with color and use it as variation.
1. Create variable product
2. Add attributes click on use as variation. (image 2 )
3. Add attribute to variations and give price to variation.

Comment: I have done that Ravi, but try to understand I am having around 45000 products, not possible to edit all manually, I am looking forward to importing all products through CSV file. take an example, if there is a product with two variations one with red color and other with wine red color, then it shows the red color, but the radio button for wine red shows white color. I have to update the HTML color hex code for wine red color manually, but dont know where.

Comment: Post another question, this is not relevant to your previous question.

Comment: i am sorry to say, but i was asking about the same thing

Comment: Use all in one import plugin